# Break or Approve multiple Pipeline's sleeptime from external script or job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am running 50 pipeline for 50 micro services using Jenkisfile and trigger the all jobs biweekly using cron. I have added a delay in pipeline so any user can approve job after checking test results and it will go for Prod deployment.

```
stage('PROD Deployment Approval') {
            // no agent, so executors are not used up when waiting for approvals
            agent none
        steps {
            script {
               def deploymentDelay = input id: 'Approve', message: 'Deploy to PROD?', submitter: 'admin', parameters: [choice(choices: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'], description: 'Hours to delay deployment?', name: 'deploymentDelay')]
               sleep time: deploymentDelay.toInteger(), unit: 'HOURS'
            }
        }
```

But instead of going in every job and provide approval. Is there any way external script or job can approve all the job which ran  ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is anything like this in Jenkins.
You could have them wait for a file in S3 to be updated or a parameter flipped or something but this would use executors.

I would suggest the best thing to do would be to end these pipelines at this stage and have another job that triggers all the prod deploy pipelines that is manually kicked off once the tests are vaildated.

Use GitOps so that the jobs end here for the dev env, then when the QA team are happy you merge the dev repo to the prod repo and the prod deploy pipelines all kickoff automatically.

Or just make the automated tested good enough to deploy to production